# filter on default address of customer

Tags: magento-1.8

I've created a functionality to search customers based on their address attributes.

To achieve this, I have created a customer collection (joining shipping and billing attributes) then added a filter according to the user input.

here's the code:

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('uuid')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')

        ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter( array(
                                    array('attribute' => 'billing_'.$this->getAttribute(),$opsymb => $value),
                                    array('attribute' => 'shipping_'.$this->getAttribute(),$opsymb => $value)
                                ));
```

I am able to search on both billing as well as shipping address. However, if address is neither billing nor shipping (no radio button selected - backend), then that address is not considered in this search.

How do I include such address which is neither billing nor shipping in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to search through the addresses then you should start with an address collection and build from there.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //optional
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('street', array('like'=>'%Something%'));
```

but in the end, when you find an address and want the customer object you need to call `load`.
Something like this.

```
foreach ($collection as $address) {
    $customerId = $address->getParentId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
}
```

If you want only the e-mail or any other field for the customer that is stored in the `customer_entity` table you can do that with a join.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //optional
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('street', array('like'=>'%Something%'));
$collection->joinTable(
    array('customer'=>'customer/entity'),
    'entity_id = parent_id',
    array('*')
);
```

This will join your collection with the customer table and you can call `$address->getEmail()`, but I don't know how you can join with the rest of the customer attributes.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a ton :)